# How to get the synset for which path_similarity score is the highest

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I understand that the following code iterates over all the synsets of `syn1` with synsets of `syn2`.

My question is, how to get the synset that gives the maximum score?

```
    from nltk.corpus import wordnet
    syn1 = wordnet.synsets('speed',pos='n')
    syn2 = wordnet.synsets('performance',pos='n')
    for word1 in syn1:
        best = max(word1.path_similarity(word2) for word2 in syn2)
        ps_list.append(best)
```

Comment: what's wrong with above code? Any error message?

Comment: No error. ps_list prints the max path_similarity between synsets of syn1 and syn2. 
ps_list = [0.1111111111111111, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1111111111111111, 0.125]
But this only gives the scores. What should I do to get name of the synsets for which I got thee maximum score?

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

syn1 = wordnet.synsets('speed',pos='n')
syn2 = wordnet.synsets('performance',pos='n')

def getMaxPath(synset1,synset2):
    sim=[]
    a=[]
    b=[]
    for i in synset1:
        for j in synset2:
            sim.append(wordnet.path_similarity(i,j))
            a.append(i.name())   # save the names from synsets1 into list
            b.append(j.name())   # save the names from synsets2 into list

    max_sim=max(sim)
    idx=np.argmax(sim)
    s1=a[idx]        # get the name of synset1 for which path sim is max
    s2=b[idx]        # get the name of synset2 for which path sim is max
    return max_sim, s1, s2

getMaxPath(syn1, syn2)
```

Output:

```
(0.2, 'speed.n.03', 'performance.n.03')
```